# How does the gradient work in higher dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

To my understanding, the gradient essentially packages together all the required partial derivatives of a function in a single structure. In 3 dimensions, the resulting vector gives the slope of steepest descent.
For example, consider the scalar valued function
$$\large f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
Its gradient with respect to $\large \mathbf{\vec x}$  is given as:
$$
\large \nabla _{\mathbf{\vec x}}f(\mathbf{\vec x}) = \left[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{\vec x})}{\partial x_{i}}\right]_{n} =   \large \begin{bmatrix}%
    \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{3}} & \dots & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{n}}%
  \end{bmatrix}%
$$
So the output of the gradient is also a vector. Here, the vector contains all partial derivatives of $\large f(\mathbf{\vec x})$ with respect to each element in $\large \mathbf{\vec x}$ .
Similarly:
$$
\large\nabla _{\mathbf{A}}f(\mathbf{A})= \left[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}_{ij}}\right]_{m \times n} \mspace{30mu}where \mspace{20mu} f: \mathbb{M}_{m, n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
Here, the matrix contains all partial derivatives of $\large f(\mathbf{\vec x})$ with respect to each element of $\large \mathbf{A}$ .

Here's my proposition
For any scalar function, its gradient's structure depends only on the value to whose respect we are taking the gradient and not on the type of input provided to the function.
For example, the gradient of a scalar matrix function with respect to a vector should also be a vector.
$$
\large \nabla _{\mathbf{\vec x}}f(\mathbf{A}) = \left[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{A})}{\partial x_{i}}\right]_{n}
$$
**Is this valid?**

Comment: I would very much argue that it's $$\nabla _{\mathbf{\vec x}}f(\mathbf{\vec x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{3}} & \dots & \frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_{n}}
  \end{bmatrix}$$ without the transpose. Gradients are supposed to be row vectors, beacuse 1) one of their main purposes is to dot multiply with regular vectors to give directional derivatives, ripe for e.g. integration, 2) how their components react to a change of coordinates, and 3) the Jacobian is a thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Is it necessary for vector multiplication that one vector be a column vector and the other a row vector because I was under the assumption that vector-vector multiplication is independent of their orientation?

Comment: Do note that a lot of calculus authors and teachers think differently, especially when teaching introductory multivariable calculus. So if your professor and your book use columns, I would suggest you stick to that, at least for the time being, to placate them, and for the sake of having consistency between lectures, notes, books, and exams. But yes, keeping it in mind is a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur The gradient $\nabla f(x)$ should be a (column) vector, whereas the derivative $Df(x)$ can be seen as a row vector. The gradient is the vector identified with the linear transformation $Df(x)$ via the inner product, i.e. $Df(x)v = \langle \nabla f(x), v \rangle$. This interpretation is good for infinite-dimensional domains too, as long as there is an inner product.

Comment: @Kakashi And I disagree. I think the gradient is the total derivative for a function that happens to have a one-dimensional codomain (column vectors are for the tenant vectors of a function that has one-dimensional domain). I have yet to see a single use of the gradient (apart from "drawing it as an arrow" and similar) where column makes sense. And for those cases, it is plainly awkward, precisely because it's actually a row vector transformed to a column vector by way of an inner product.

Comment: Is the orientation of a vector really an important trait? Aren't most vector operations, such as inner and outer products, independent of their orientations(whether row or column)?